# Selective redshift copy command from parquet file format

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, parquet

Is there any way to selectively copy certain fields from a parquet file?  I have the ddl of the parquet file (from a gluecrawler), but a basic copy command into redshift fails because of arrays present in the file.  Ideally, I would like to parse out the data into several different tables (i.e., an array would become its own table), but doing so would require the ability to selectively copy.  Any ideas appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: you could redshift spectrum and then a simple ctas to select just the columns you need.

Comment: any other approaches than using spectrum? (i'm in an org where launching clusters requires going through a lot of hoops).

Comment: spectrum is the easiest way - and is simple to set up (you dont need to launch a new cluster)